# Angularjs. How can I pass variable as argument to custom filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following HTML

```
<span class="items-count">{{items | countmessage}}</span>
```

And following filter to show right count message

```
    app.filters
    .filter('countmessage', function () {
        return function (input) {
            var result = input.length + ' item';
            if (input.length != 1) result += 's';
            return message;
        }
    });
```

but I want use different words instead 'item(s)', so I modified the filter

```
    app.filters
    .filter('countmessage', function () {
        return function (input, itemType) {
            var result = input.length + ' ' + itemType;
            if (input.length != 1) result += 's';
            return message;
        }
     });
```

it works when I use a string like that

```
<span class="items-count">{{items | countmessage:'car'}}</span>
```

but doesn't work with a variable from the $scope, is it possible to use $scope variable

```
<span class="items-count">{{items | countmessage:itemtype}}</span>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use variable from the `$scope`

See this fiddle for an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/lopisan/Kx4Tq/

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <input ng-model="variable"/><br/>
        Live output: {{variable | countmessage : type}}!<br/>
          Output: {{1 | countmessage : type}}!
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['myApp.filters']);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.type = 'cat';
}

 angular.module('myApp.filters', [])
    .filter('countmessage', function () {
        return function (input, itemType) {
            var result = input + ' ' + itemType;
            if (input >  1) result += 's';
            return result;
        }
     });
```

Comment: ok thanks, I found it already, I just missed my variable for the current scope, it works now.

Comment: Can we generate the $scope.type dynamically through user input? Such as: `<input type='text' ng-model='searchTerm'>`?

Comment: @Clever: Yes it can be done, just add `<input ng-model="type"/>` to the HTML part of the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. After a few hours of headbanging yesterday, I found my issue was actually a child-parent scope inheritance problem stemming from ng-include.